# Set different borders thickness for the table heading style format

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm trying to use a style I'm used to have on Latex, where the heading would have the upper border with a thicker line that the interior/bottom border. In the style configuration, it seems that I don't have such liberties. When I set the border line thickness or color, it does for the all active borders. Is there a way short of manually setting the thickness for all tables?

What I want:

[image]

Note how the top and bottom lines are thicker than the middle one.

Comment: @RichMichaels I didn't add more specs. I added an image to illustrate what I wanted, as it's done in Latex, which was already described on the question. I described it using the same terminology as does MS Word (heading, border, etc.) That answerers instead of clarifying when they are unsure, answer the question, is not my problem. I evaluate answers given as the question is stated, and the question states what I want: in table styles, how to configure different border thickness for the heading.

Comment: @RichMichaels my question stays the same: first row, thick line on the top, thin line on the bottom. The text and the image both are in agreement. Why are you still arguing that your answer fixes my issue? It doesn't You are changing the whole table borders, I want to change **only the first row**. How would your answer allow the first row to have different thickness in any of its borders? It doesn't, because you are editing the whole table style. Click that "Apply formatting to:" drop down, and you will see a "heading" entry. Try to apply borders of different thickness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written out a detailed procedure for you to follow and included it as 5 screen captures from the Word document that I wrote the procedure in. The New Table Style dialog is where you perform this process.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ok, that was pretty unintuitive. You have to set borders on two different windows. Btw, could you please, type the answer instead of using image as text, since that affects accessibility.

Comment: That's why I said it's tricky. I know the guy at MS who designed this and it wasn't his most shinning moment. :-(

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom table style. I recommend to only base it on the Table Normal style. To create it you start from the same New Style dialog but choose Table from the Type menu.

Use the Borders and Shading control from the Format button of the New Table Style dialog, don't use the little pull-down icon near the color control.

Once created you access your Custom Table Style from the contextual Table Design tab that opens when your selection point is within the table. All further modification or applications of the custom table are made from the Table Design Tab and not the normal Styles Task Pane.

[image]

Table Styles can be a bit tricky to deal with. If you search the web for **AuthorTec Tables** there is a free add-in for Word that you can read about and see if will help you.

Comment: @Braiam, I initially misread your question and skipped over the fact you were looking for a custom table style. I've deleted my other answer, which focused on paragraph styles.

Comment: This still doesn't fulfill my requirements, since why you don't have a different border for header top and bottom. The first line needs to have different border above and below, I don't care about other lines. See the example on the quesiton.